# Is there any alternative to iframe, object or embed?

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

I want to include an external (external domain) html page into my page. For SEO reasons iframe, object or embed are not useful, there are just a link in my source file. PHP's include function is very helpful but it causes many problems for UI. I want contents of include function and view of iframe.

How can I do that? 
Thanks.

Comment: How is it bad for SEO? Do you want to use the content of the other site for your SEO purposes? That will only have a negative impact on their SEO.

Comment: I did not know that. Thank you.

Comment: Actually it's my own content on different domains.

Comment: Ah. Different server too? Otherwise you could share a database, or still, just sync the raw data between domains. But be careful. Sharing the same content between domains makes them cannibalize each other's page rank. It's better to have one at the top than to have two on the second result page.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reasonable alternative to `<iframe>`.

Who knows if you could extract the markup from the site from the server-side and print that HTML inside a `<div>` in your own site, but I doubt that this could ever work, because if the whole target site does AJAX requests, WebSockets or whatever, **it should be secure enough to block you from performing them from other domains than allowed ones by themselves (i.e. *their official domains*).**

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding content from an external source the it should really have 0 impact on your SEO. Needs to be your own content as far as I am aware. You could try scraping the external source and using Ajax add it to your page using $().load() or similar... Wouldn't recommend though!